# Transformation for Animation

Tags: android, animation, matrix, transformation

I've come from an iOS background where there was a property called `transform` which was essentially just a 4x4 matrix for a 3D transformation that is applied to a `CALayer` (Also `UIView`).

I have come across the [Transformation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html) class, which seems to be a bit different, but I'm hoping that I can use it for some transformations on a `View` subclass.

I have seen the constructor `new Transformation()` and the different `set` methods, but I can't see anything that will allow me to actually set the 3x3 matrix for the `Transformation` or how it is used on a `View`.

I would guess that this isn't a very important class, either, as there seem to be errors in the document itself.

I was hoping that someone on SO might be able to help me figure out how to utilize this class to get transformations working on my `View` subclasses (How to construct and apply a `Transformation`) or point me towards a better tool/class for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You'd typically apply a transformation within an Animation object in Android. i.e. Create a new Animation class that sets a transform for your view:

```
public class myAnimation extends Animation {
  public myAnimation() { }

  @Override
  boolean   willChangeTransformationMatrix() { return true; }

  @Override
  void  applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    Matrix m = t.getMatrix();
    // do whatever you want to the matrix here, using the interpolatedTime
  }
}
```

Then set the animation on your view:

```
Animation anim = new myAnimation();
anim.setDuration(100);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

On post Honeycomb Android, you should be able to do similar things just by manipulating the matrix on a view though:

```
Matrix m = view.getMatrix();
// do whatever you want here
```